# When we use three.js loader.load() ,how to save callback's argument in a global variable

Tags: javascript, three.js

Please look at the code first:

```
    var o = null;
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load("../model/Ban.stl",function(obj){
        o = obj;
        objectSTL = new THREE.Mesh(obj,mesh3);
        objectSTL.scale.set(0.06,0.06,0.06)
        wheelCenterPoint.add(objectSTL);
        console.log(1)
    });
    console.log(o);
```

the information that the chrome output is :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8jQx.png)

chrome print “null” first,and then "1", so, I want to ask how to make "o" save "obj"?

Comment: `o` will be not `null` right after the object will be loaded and `function(obj){...}` will be called. Loading is asynchronous, that's why you get `null` and then `1`.

Comment: so what should i do ?

Comment: Depends on what you want to achieve. What do you try to do with the `o` variable while it's null? it's better to provide jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: I want to set the property of  `o` at outside,like following:             var o = null;
    var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
    loader.load("../model/Ban.stl",function(obj){
        o = obj;
        objectSTL = new THREE.Mesh(obj,mesh3);
        objectSTL.scale.set(0.06,0.06,0.06)
        wheelCenterPoint.add(objectSTL);
        console.log(1)
    });           o.rotation.x = Math.PI;

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want to achieve, saying _to set the property of o at outside_.

Comment: now I can just set property of `mesh` like this :   loader.load("../model/Ban.stl",function(obj){
        objectSTL = new THREE.Mesh(obj,mesh3);
        objectSTL.scale.set(2,2,2);
    });
    I want do this work like this : 
    var objectSTL;
   loader.load("../model/Ban.stl",function(obj){
        objectSTL = new THREE.Mesh(obj,mesh3);
        
    });
    objectSTL.scale.set(2,2,2);